# Resetting value of NumberPicker inside ListView item

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, numberpicker

I have a `ListView` activity that has a `NumberPicker` view on each item in the list. The user can use this picker to add/remove items. It is working however the issue I have is that when I resume the `ListView` activity the values are still at the chosen values when I would like them to be set to 0.

Is there any way I can do this?
So far I have done the following inside my `MenuItemArrayAdapter` class I add a method to reset the number picker.

```
public class MenuItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem>{

private List<MenuItem> menuItems;
private List<MenuItem> order;
private static NumberPicker np;
private TextView price;
private double amount = 0.0;
private double total = 0.0;

//Constructor
public MenuItemArrayAdapter(Context context, List<MenuItem> menuItems, TextView price) {
    super(context, R.layout.menuitem_row, menuItems);
    this.menuItems = menuItems;
    this.price = price;
    order = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

}

public MenuItemArrayAdapter(Context context){
    super(context, R.layout.menuitem_row);
}

//get views
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;


    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.menuitem_row, null);
        v.setFocusable(true);
    }

    //assign values to view
    final MenuItem item = this.menuItems.get(position);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    final TextView priceView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

    nameView.setText(item.getName() + " ");
    priceView.setText("€"+ String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    //number picker
    np = (NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.numpick);
    np.setMaxValue(20);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setValue(0);
    np.setFocusable(false);
    //calculation occurs when values are changed...
    np.setOnValueChangedListener( new OnValueChangeListener() {
          public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "dish: " + item.getName() + " amount: " + picker.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "new Value: " + newVal + " old Value: " + oldVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               // amount += item.getPrice() * picker.getValue();

                if(newVal > oldVal){
                    total = (item.getPrice() * newVal) - item.getPrice() * oldVal;
                    //add to order
                    order.add(item);
                    amount += total;
                    Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "ADDED TO ORDER: " + item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                if(newVal < oldVal){
                    total = (item.getPrice() * oldVal) - item.getPrice() * newVal;
                    //remove from order
                    order.remove(item);
                    amount -= total;
                    Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "REMOVED FROM ORDER: " + item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                price.setText("€" + String.valueOf(amount));
            }
          });

    return v;

}

public List<MenuItem> getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void resetNumberPicker(){
    np.setValue(0);
}
```

}

I then call this method in the ListView activity:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            adapter = new MenuItemArrayAdapter(StartersActivity.this, starters, price);
            adapter.resetNumberPicker();
            StartersActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);              
        }
    }
```

but i get this error:

**FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.waitron5.MenuItemArrayAdapter.resetNumberPicker(MenuItemArrayAdapter.java:104)**

this is the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at com.example.waitron5.MenuItemArrayAdapter.resetNumberPicker(MenuItemArrayAdapter.java:104)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at com.example.waitron5.StartersActivity$HTTPTask.onPostExecute(StartersActivity.java:215)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at com.example.waitron5.StartersActivity$HTTPTask.onPostExecute(StartersActivity.java:1)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-21 18:04:40.053: E/AndroidRuntime(18291):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is occuring at this line 104:

```
np.setValue(0);
```

I realise that it is perhaps because I am not getting a reference to the `NumberPicker` np. But How can I fix my code so that this will not return an NPE?

Comment: have u tried to check np for NULL before calling setValue ?

Comment: I did this `if(np!=null)np.setValue(0)` and that stopped the crashing, however the issue is that when the activity is reloaded the values in the number picker have not been reset

Comment: "activity is reloaded" means starting it again ? then u will need to call resetNumberPicker method in Activity on Resume

Comment: yes sorry I should have been more specific. I have done that but the problem is still present. Is there a way I can reset the NumberPicker inside of the `getView()` method of the MenuItemArrayAdapter class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't(and you shouldn't) connect to the row views created in the `getView()` method like you did(you also don't need that static `NumberPicker` field in the adapter). As you always set the value of the `NumberPicker` to `0` in the `getView()` method you could try simply calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `resetNumberPicker()` method.